# How to view Oracle table column character set?

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

In Oracle, we can use desc  to return the column width of each column.

Are there any commands that we can retrieve the characterset of each column?

(for example, AL32UTF8, WE8MSWIN1252)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 23):

A column doesn't have a character set in Oracle.  A database has a character set and a national character set.  All `char`, `varchar2`, and `clob` columns use the database character set.  All `nchar`, `nvarchar2`, and `nclob` columns use the national character set.

You can see both character sets by running

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```