# national dialect with different NLS_LANG

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle DB with character set to EE8ISO8859P2, and I want to insert a arabic, or russian (UTF8) records.
When I do:

```
select CONVERT('العربية', 'EE8ISO8859P2', 'AL32UTF8') from dual
```

it shows "???????". How can I use national dialects without changing a character set of oracle?
Sorry 4 my english;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [character sets your database supports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34890980/1509264):

```
SELECT *
FROM   v$nls_parameters
WHERE  parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

Which will hopefully output something like:

```
PARAMETER              | VALUE    
:--------------------- | :-----------
NLS_CHARACTERSET       | EE8ISO8859P2
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET | AL32UTF8
```

If the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is UTF8 (or another similar encoding) then don't use `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2` datatypes but use `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR2` datatypes instead:

```
SELECT N'العربية' FROM DUAL;
```